# How to write a shell script that will add two numbers?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

Assuming that the inputs are given as command line arguments and if two numbers are not given show a error message as "command line arguments are missing".

Sample output:

addition of 1 and 2 is 3.

Comment: Show your attempt

Comment: echo "Enter two numbers"
read num1 num2
sum=`expr $num1 + $num2`
echo "the sum of $num1 and $num2 is $sum"

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: [Plz email me teh codez](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
    echo "command line arguments are missing "
else
    echo $(($1+$2))
fi
```

Comment: `$[...]` is an obsolete `bash` extension. It should never be used anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

In `awk`:

```
echo 5 5 | awk  '{ print $1 + $2}'
10
```

Answer (score 2):

actualNumber=720;
 incrementNo=1;

actualNumber=$(expr "$actualNumber" + "$incrementNo");

echo $actualNumber

Answer (score 0):

DESCRIPTION:
This script will read two integer value from users and give output as sum of two values
SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter the first number : "
read num1
echo -n "Enter the second number : "
read num2
sum=`expr $num1 + $num2`
echo "sum of two value is $sum"
```

RUN:

```
sh sum.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to put all in one place.

```
num1=10 
num2=20 
 
sum=$(( $num1 + $num2 )) 
 
sum=`expr $num1 + $num2` 
 
sum=$[num1+num2] 
 
sum=$(echo $num1 $num2 | awk '{print $1 + $2}') 
 
sum=$(expr $num1 + $num2) 
 
sum=$(expr "$num1" + "$num2")
```